# Unable to download with wget

Tags: wget

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/sources/s/setuptools/setuptools-1.1.6.tar.gz
```

I have used above link to download ,but I am getting the error as

```
Resolving pypi.python.org (pypi.python.org)... 185.31.18.223
Connecting to pypi.python.org (pypi.python.org)|185.31.18.223|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-05-02 14:54:20 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: Your URL is incorrect.

Comment: any problem with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

404 mean that the server can't find the resource. Meaning that you have a wrong link.

In this link you can find the packages to download:

https://pypi.python.org/simple/setuptools/

Try this:

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/cb/0f/14c41a82f571530a259d6961632a92327a6c84a7a802a03409e46325be99/setuptools-1.1.6.zip#md5=17838c189ea368fc58007f5ccd816f31
```